# Validate range with java Date and SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, validation, date, range

Is there a Date exception that I can deal with when I try to parse a date with this code here:

```
try{
   SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MM:yyyy"); 
   Date date = df.parse(dateRelease);
}catch (ParseException e) {}
```

Well, if the "dateRelease" isn't in a correct format type it throws ParseException, but I want to get if someone write like "40/03/2010" - WRONG with day, month or year invalid range. Actually, when a invalid date is sent, SimpleDateFormat just create a new Date with default numbers.

Do I have to create my own method with a regex to deal with it or is there an existing exception that tells me it to catch?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are looking for exactly? It seems like you're looking for some type of exception to tell you if some validation failed? That's not really what exceptions are for.

Comment: hmm, I want to know if the user typed date has a valid day, month or year range. If not, it shows the fail and not create the object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make it non-lenient by [`SimpleDateFormat#setLenient()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29) with a value of `false`.

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MM:yyyy"); 
df.setLenient(false);
Date date = df.parse(dateRelease);
```

Then it will throw `ParseException` when the date is not in a valid range.

Comment: thank you man, that's what I was searching for! (worked)

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
try {
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( 
        "40:03:2010" ,    // "40:03:2010" is bad input, "27:03:2010" is good input.
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd:MM:uuuu" )
    ) ;
} catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {
    …  // Invalid input detected.
}
```

## Using java.time

The modern way is with the java.time classes built into Java 8 and later.

Your example data does not match the format shown in your example code. One uses SOLIDUS (slash) character, the other uses COLON character. I'll go with COLON.

### `DateTimeFormatter`

Define a formatting pattern to match the input string.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd:MM:uuuu" );
```

### `LocalDate`

Parse as a `LocalDate` object as the input has no time-of-day and no time zone.

```
LocalDate localDateGood = LocalDate.parse( "27:03:2010" , f );
System.out.println( "localDateGood: " + localDateGood );
```

Now try some bad input. Trap for the appropriate exception.

```
try {
    LocalDate localDateBad = LocalDate.parse( "40:03:2010" , f );
} catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {
    System.out.println( "ERROR - Bad input." );
}
```

See this [code run live in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/Unk4jO).

> localDateGood: 2010-03-27
>
> ERROR - Bad input.

### ISO 8601

Use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats when exchanging/storing date-time values as text. The standard formats are sensible, practical, easily read by humans of various cultures, and easy for machines to parse.

For a date-only value the standard format is YYYY-MM-DD such as `2010-03-27`.

The java.time classes use standard ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So **no need to specify a formatting pattern** at all.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( "2010-03-27" );
String output = localDate.toString();  // 2010-03-27
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).